# Align H1 Header and Normal Text in Same Line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a H1 header and regular text on the same line, with a line under it, like so:

[image]

I have tried below code, but have been unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<div style="border-bottom:1px;"> 
    <div align="left"><h1>Header</h1></div>
    <div align="right">Regular Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 46):

### Original answer (still working just fine)

See the snippet below. The idea is to make the `<h1>` inline to allow the second text to be at the same line.

```css
header { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
header > h1 { display: inline-block; }
header span { margin-left: 100px; }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <span>text2</span>
</header>
```

### 2020 Update

See the snippet the snippet below that makes use of Flexbox. So instead of setting the h1 to an `inline-block`, you can make the header a `flex` container. A flex container will (by default) layout its children on a horizontal axis.

Note that you also need `align-items: center` to keep the h1 and span on the same vertical axis. Also, note that you might want `align-items: baseline` if you want the texts to appear on the same baseline (like my original answer).

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Remove the next line if you want the span to appear next to the h1 */
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <span>at the end</span>
</header>
```

Comment: If you just want to modify this specific header, you could just inline the style as https://codepen.io/sefeng/pen/vYYXROW

Answer (score 7):

I came up with a simple solution.  My requirements are slightly different in that I want my status right aligned.

```css
.my-header h2 { 
  display: inline;
}
.my-header span { 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-header">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <span>Status</span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line `border-bottom:1px solid #000`

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;"> 
<div align="left"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div align="right">Regular Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/253/)

Use class name instead of inline-style.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div style="float:left;"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div style="float:right;">Regular Text Goes Here</div>
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to accomplish H1 and TEXT inline. To clarify, TXT is in an element container. You suggest DIV, but any symantic element will do. Below, h1 and p illustrate a common use, while showing that you need not hide from element blocking, using DIV's (though divs are pandemic for many javascript coders).

Method 1

```
.inline { display: inline; float: left; padding-right: 2rem; }
<h5 class="inline">Element a's link family...</h5>
<p class="inline">
```

Method 2

```
h5 { display: inline-block; float: left; font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1rem; margin-right: 2rem; }
h5>p { display: inline-block; float: right; }
<h5>Title</h5>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write like this :-

**HTML**

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; overflow:hidden;"> 
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="right">Regular Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
float:left;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0;
}
.right {
float:right;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/JxPTIrtF)

**EVEN YOU CAN USE THIS METHOD ALSO WITH MINIMIZED MARKUP** :- [DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/WCyFC30G)

Comment: links are dead now