# How to get page-header and nav-pills to appear on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the header of my web page to be centered in the screen. The heading called 'Yawning Yeti' should be at the center, and the nav-pills should be to the right of that. Although I am able to get the nav-pills to the right, they appear to be one line below 'Yawning Yeti'.

You can see the page here: http://jsbin.com/cazokija/1/

I tried the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194692/align-h1-header-and-normal-text-in-same-line) but that didn't affect the html in any visible manner. Here is my CSS:

```
.page-header{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none; 
}​

.page-header > h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Yawning Yeti</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="center-pills">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">bigfoot <span class="badge">+42</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">nessie <span class="badge">3</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I make it so the nav-pills are to the right of 'Yawning Yeti', on the same line, and occupying  70% of the screen at the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you have `pull-left` or `pull-right` components, they should appear before other "non-pull" components.

In your case, you would need to put `<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">` before `<div class="text-center">` like this: http://jsbin.com/cazokija/31